# Internationalizing the browser generated confirm Window

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am looking forward to create a custom Navigation Window and trying to internationalize it. I have created my own modal of confirm window using simple html and css, i have pretty confused how to integrate it. 
When ever a form is being filled and the user navigates to any button it should show the confirm window.

Comment: there must be  `confirm("message")`, `alert("message")` or `prompt("message")` somewhere in your code. try to look for it and pass the translated message to it.

Comment: as for the integration, we are bound by the **Realm** of ***Reality***,  we can't help you much without the code. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯